# What does the $m mean in R?

Tags: r

[image]

I'm trying to understand this piece of code from [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dlm/vignettes/dlm.pdf) for the dlm Filtering function, but do not understand what the purpose of $m is.

Comment: Your way of phrasing the question is odd. `$m` has no special meaning in R, but `$` does. If you don't yet know the meaning of `$` in R, you need to spend some time with a basic tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

In the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dlm/dlm.pdf) of the `dlmFilter` function, in the "Value" part, `m` is:

> Time series (or matrix) of filtered values of the state vectors.  The series startsone time unit before the first observation.

Therefore, `nileJumpFilt$m` returns this matrix.